# MS Access (office 365) linked tables to SQL server are giving me date fields with the day of the year appended to the year

Tags: date, ms-access, format

MS Access is converting SQL Server date format "2023-01-01" into 01.01.20231
or "2023-02-28" into 28.02.202359.
The appended number is the day of the year. Anyone have an idea why.

It is nothing to do with the linked tables I just tested with an Access table and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date value carries no format, so somehow your local date/time format has been set to something like `dd.mm.yyyyn`.

In Access, try in the Immidiate window:

```
? Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

It should return as your date separator seems to be a dot:

```
02.03.2024
```

Comment: My date/time format is dd.MM.yyyy, Excel works as expected. Somewhere in Access is obviously (now that you  pointed it out) something bent out of shape.  The work-around for me is to use a view based on the table with the date manually formated. I will have a poke around in the registry and see what turns up

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the date format in Windows settings to US style and then back to german style manually. That was after trolling through the registry, uninstalling office, reinstalling office in french (didn't help), uninstalling office, reinstalling english office, tearing at hair (didn't take long, there's not a lot left)